# Worth it to have many subdocuments in mongoose model

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am developing a restaurant model with mongoose.

I want a restaurant document to have an array of category subdocs, category to have an array of dish subdoc and dish also to have an array of portion subdoc.

Does it seem to be good or I should split the data among several collections?

Comment: the food is the most important thing, portions and categories are details of food. i would model the data like Restaurant > Menu > Dishes > DishPortions, DishCategory. But i havent worked with mongo collections so i don't have specific advice about implementing that model in mongo, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a several collections, with ref's to parent/child collection.

Example in mongoose:

```
const Category = new Schema({
    name: String,
    dishes: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'dish'
    }]
});

const Dish = new Schema({
    categories: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Category'
    }],
    name: String,
    price: Number
});
```

you can use one-way relation (only child or parent), depending on your logic.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html